Netbeans Tools->Options->Java->Maven window is empty
Ubuntu 24.04. Maven is installed in system. Netbeans don't show any options of Maven. Cannot create Maven Java app either.
I checked other Options tabs in Java subtab. GUI Builder and Java Shell are empty too. This bug was with Ubuntu 22.04 on the same computer.

Here is screenshot https://i.postimg.cc/jdxdNPmc/Screenshot-from-2024-05-01-14-37-10.png

How to solve this problem?

After activating installed plugins in this (picture) list maven appeared in its window. https://i.postimg.cc/wBYWtJQV/Screenshot-from-2024-05-01-20-23-54.png Hope this will help someone

Solved by activating already installed plugins...
